# Requesting help to understand & how to initiate a typescript array of a class

Tags: typescript

I broke it down to these two items MapComponent and a GeoPoint class.
What am  I missing here?

**MapComponent**

- Are either of these the proper way to create an array of a class I've made so it is not undefined?
- If not what is the correct way?

```
    // Initiate
    const response: Array<LatLngExpression> = []; // Seems to work
    const response: [LatLngExpression] = [];      // Msg: Type any[] is not assignable to type [any]
    // Add a value to the array
    response.push(geoPoint.getLatLng());
```

**GeoPoint**

```
export clas GeoPoint {
  private _id: string;
  private _value: LatLngExpression; // This is a leaflet.LatLngExpression
  private _selected: boolean = false;

  constructor (id: string, latLng:LatLngExpression, selected?:boolean) {
    this._id = id;
    this._value = latLng;
    if(selected){
      this._selected = selected;
    }
  }

  set()... // you get the idea
  get()... // you get the idea
}
```

Comment: `const response: [LatLngExpression]` says `response` is an array with a single element of type `LatLngExpression`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Seems to work" one is correct:

```
const response: Array<LatLngExpression> = [];
```

You can also write it like this:

```
const response: LatLngExpression[] = [];
```

`LatLngExpression[]` is the type of `response`.

Ths is covered in the Handbook in the [Basic Types > Array section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array).

---

In many cases you could also leave off the type entirely and allow TypeScript to infer it. But if you're starting with an empty array, that's actually more awkward than just providing the type annotation because you have to provide a type assertion instead. So it's probably not what you want, but just for completeness:

```
// I probably wouldn't do it this way
const response = [] as LatLngExpression[];
```

Comment: @Elijah - I don't know if the TypeScript team have a preference; there's none expressed in the linked documentation unless you want to infer one from the fact they show the `LatLngExpression[]` style first. Personally, I prefer the `LatLngExpression[]` style not least because it's similar to other languages (Java, C#), but I'm not a TypeScript guru (at ***all***). :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some additionnal information to help you understand everything:

- In `const response: [LatLngExpression]`, the type `[LatLngExpression]` specifies a one-item **tuple**, i.e. an array with one and only one item of `LatLngExpression` type.
- To specify the type of a regular array, use this syntax: `LatLngExpression[]`.
- The value `[]` as the inferred type `any[]` i.e. an array with items of any type (compatible with `[LatLngExpression]`) and of any length *(incompatible with the one-item-tuple `[LatLngExpression]`, forcing `length === 1`)*.
- To declare an empty array of a given item type, there are several options:

  - `const response: LatLngExpression[] = [];` recommanded
  - `const response: Array<LatLngExpression> = [];` not idiomatic in TypeScript
  - `const response = new Array<LatLngExpression>;`: correct inferred type but not idiomatic in JavaScript
  - `const response = [] as LatLngExpression[];` is based on a "type assertion" which is more permissive then more risky (can accept unexpected value). It's not recommanded to specify the type of a variable. But it's the usual way to do with an inline expression (i.e. without intermediary variable) to specify an empty array of a given type: `([] as LatLngExpression[])`.

By the way, we can initialize directly the array with an initial value this way: `const response = [geoPoint.getLatLng()];`. It's terser and we still have the correct inferred type `LatLngExpression[]`.

TypeScript can be confusing because syntax for types is closed to the syntax for values (regular JavaScript code), but with some subtle differences like `[a]` (value) that has type `A[]` (where `A = typeof(a)`) and not `[A]`. Indeed, a tuple cannot be inferred easily and it's recommanded to give explicit type to tuple: `const tuple: [A] = [a];`.

Comment: Thank you for the educational lesson. This kind of response is rather hard to get from Googling so it really is appreciated.